# I need to delete . in my data

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, data, r

I have a data file with 4 columns.
4th column is real variable with 5 decimals followed by 0.
I need to remove the "." in this column.
I tried using sed command in R

```
system(paste('sed s/./""/g <"map1.txt" > "map.txt"',sep=""))
```

but it doesn't work.
Can you suggest me the solution?

Comment: can you post the sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

The `R` command is unnecessarily complicated, for example you don't need `paste` in this example. The double-quotes are very strangely positioned, and the `sed` command is incorrect. Here's the fix:

```
system('sed "s/\\.//" < map1.txt > map.txt')
```

Note that the `\\` is necessary instead of simply `\` because of the way `R` interprets strings.

Comment: Hello Janos This worked. Thanks a lot for your help.